# Expres JS admin panel

Tags: express, admin, mern

How does express js come in the usage where it doesn't have a built-in admin panel? If there's an admin panel I can use readily, please refer one.

I tried Admin Js, but it's not reliable I guess. Because it's in baby-phase still. I'm deciding to stay away from MERM Stack because of it's lack of a built-in admin panel. I mean would I tolerate the hazard of making an admin panel every time for every client? Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, unfortunately there is not a built-in panel, anyway keep supporting the mern community, here is a website with plenty of ideas https://reactjsexample.com/tag/admin-template/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).